# Как добавить возможность масштабировать WebView двумя пальцами?

Tags: android, java

Приложение корректно открывает странички, но не масштабирует по умолчанию. Можно ли включить эту функцию и как?

Comment: Похоже, нашел ответ здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195310/android-webview-zooming-using-the-scaledetector#3195310

    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

Жаль пока нет возможности затестить, пока реальное устройство не придет. Пока это выглядит как пара дополнительных кнопок в эмуляторе для масштаба и не понятно, останутся ли они в приложении или это так эмулятор обрабатывает.

Comment: В приложении они останутся и от них не избавиться.